# Sending email with Python, the msg["Subject"] variable doesn't behave as it should

Tags: python, email, mime

I'm sending emails with Python, but the msg["Subject"] variable populates the body of the email instead of the subject box, and the variable body, populates nothing...

Everything else works fine, but I can't figure out why the subject is the body and the body is empty?
What have I missed?

Here's the code:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = "myemail@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = 'anemail@hotmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = "for next delivery, please supply"

body = Merged_Dp_Ind_str
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

text = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login('username@gmail.com', 'password1')
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg['Subject'])
server.quit()
```

[screenshot of the inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tRo3.png)

Comment: you may want to change your password....

Comment: If you also look at the syntax highlighting again, you can see that the line `msg['From'] = "myemail@gmail.com'` is incorrect. You open the string with a `"`, but don't end it correctly, because you end with a `'` (and not `"`). So it should be correct: `msg['From'] = "myemail@gmail.com"`

Comment: editing the post does not delete previous values, we can still see your password, make sure to actually change it

Comment: Yes, it was a copy/paste mistake. I also changed my password, thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your message is fine, but you are not actually *sending* it; you are only sending the Subject.

> ```
> server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg['Subject'])
> ```

You apparently mean

```py
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], text)
```

However, you should probably update your code to use the modern Python 3.6+ APIs instead.

The proper modern way to format and send the message is something like

```py
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['From'] = "myemail@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = 'anemail@hotmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = "for next delivery, please supply"
msg.set_content(Merged_Dp_Ind_str)

with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as server:
    server.starttls()
    server.login('username@gmail.com', 'password1')
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()
```